# Delete Safari cookies from Terminal

Tags: macos, cookies, terminal, safari

I need to delete all Safari cookies from terminal. Of course, I've found couple of topics describing how to do that ([Erase Safari cookies from Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899851/erase-safari-cookies-from-terminal) or [How to delete Safari cookies from OS 10.7.2 terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781541/how-to-delete-safari-cookies-from-os-10-7-2-terminal/8782074#8782074)), but nothing works for me.

When I delete cookies like `~/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies` (I do that for all files in Cookies dir), 
they always reappear when I reopen Safari. In the other topic, I found that you should first stop process `killall cookied`, but when I engage such command, system responds that no matching processes were found (I tried that as both signed in user and sudo).

Can anyone help me please? I'm running OS X 10.11.4 El Capitan.